# How to make regex to catch optional group

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find expression that will bring to me 2 or three groups into array, while the third group is optional (can be or not to be)
here is expression i use so far:

```
var expr = /^\s*(.+)\s+in\s+(.*?)\s*$/
```

if user only have 'thing in Things' - i want matches array to be as following:

```
[1] - thing

[2] - Things
```

if user have 'thing in Things | orderBy "id"' - i want matches array to be as following:

```
[1] - thing

[2] - Things

[3] - | orderBy "id"
```

```
console.log('2:'+'thing in Things'.match(expr)[2])  //-want it to be "Things" 
console.log('3:'+'thing in Things | orderBy "id"'.match(expr)[3])  //want it to be 'orderBy "id"''  (currently - undefined)
```

here is link to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/UYUxAluS/2/edit) that demonstates problem:

Thanks forwards

Comment: Do you mean you want to split the string by both `in` and `|`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:
`/^\s*(.+)\s+in\s+(.*?)\s*(?:\s+\|\s+(.*))?$/`

[image: Regular expression visualization]